# Delete multiple items from List

Tags: android, list

I have made a custom adapter with checkbox and I want to delete checked item(s) from list.

Even I tried with

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, <Array Items>);
```

But failed to remove multiple items.

Answer (score 1):

I can't actually think of anything else rather than of refreshing your list view:

> this.expAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

since i'm working on list view myself and data deletes just nice. No need to recreate anything, just be sure you are modifying the data source your adapter is using (and not a copy of it, for example) and notify him that you changed data after you are done.